# "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Tags: java, maven

How to resolve this error?

> "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

I did find the following explanation for what the message meant that was quite helpful:

> "That error means you have some unresolved dependency, i.e. one of those jar files depends on some other jar file that you have not added to your classpath."

Comment: Self answering question is OK, but you need to separate question section from answer section. Next time when you want to self answer your question when you post it check "Answer your own question" mark and you will see section for answer.

Comment: Also consider deleting answer part from your question (use [edit] option for that), and post it using "Post your answer" option (under your question).

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to update my maven dependencies in the main project pom.xml file. I made the following changes and the problem went away.

```
aspectj-maven-plugin 1.5 -> 1.7
maven-compiler-plugin 3.0 -> 3.3
aspectjweaver to 1.7.3 -> 1.8.6
```

So the discovery is that when you have these sorts of errors, make sure sure all the dependencies are up to date

Answer (score 0):

For NetBeans, my solution was to use a later ecj.jar file, ecj-4.4.2.jar